# excel 2013 copy data from column A sheet 1 to column A sheet 2 and 3

Tags: excel

I have a work book with multiple sheets. 
I want the infomation in sheet 1 column A to populate in sheet 2 and 3.
I have used " =sheet1!a10 " and that works to a point. When I have to change the data on sheet 1, either insert or delete a row, theh formula does not carry over. Also I am counting the rows, and using " =sheet1!a10 " puts a number value in addition cells throwing off the percentage.
is there a way to lock the formula in a cell and also not count empty cells?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your **first** problem.  In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROWS($1:1))="","",INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROWS($1:1)))
```

and copy down...................This is tolerant of inserting/deleting cells in *Sheet1*  column **A.**

I would use a separate column to remove any blanks from *Sheet1* data.

**EDIT#1:**

Since the above gathers data from column **A**, we can use something similar to get get from any column, say column **B**

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B" & ROWS($1:1))="","",INDIRECT("Sheet1!B" & ROWS($1:1)))
```

Comment: This worked great. As for the counting, I had to ad the sheet # in the count formula..."COUNTA(Sheet1!A1:A200) to the successive sheets, in order to get the right number to show up.

Comment: I am finding out that this code worked almost the way I need it to. The only problem is that in succesive sheets (sheet 2 and sheet 3) only column A is deleted and the rest of the columns still have data remaining. Is there an add on to that code that would remove the whole row on the additional sheets? JEFF

Comment: How would I then chhange it to remove the whole row ie A through L? I've tried "," ":" "-" and "_" all of which came back "REF!"

Comment: would making the cells in the corresponding row on sheet 2, 3 ect, cause the data to delete or insert, dependent on cell A1, A2, A3 ect be possible as well?

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone looking at this, the simplest solution is to simply group the sheets together; hold down ctrl and then click each tab you want to affect, and then what ever you do in any of the tabs will carry over to the other sheets. 
Easy Day